# Pronouns in a clause

Tags: pronoun

I have a doubt about the pronoun "es" in this clause:

> Aber auch schon abends, sobald das Licht brennt, sieht der Verstand wie das Auge nicht so klar, wie bei Tage: daher diese Zeit nicht zur Meditation ernster, zumal unangenehmer Angelegenheiten geeignet ist. Hierzu ist der Morgen die rechte Zeit; **wie er es denn überhaupt** zu allen Leistungen ohne Ausnahme, sowohl den geistigen wie den körperlichen, **ist**. <sup>[A. Schopenhauer: Aphorismen](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/aphorismen-4996/7)</sup>

Does "es" refer to "die rechte Zeit"? Shouldn't it be "sie" instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hie**r**zu ist der Morgen **die rechte Zeit**; wie er **es** überhaupt zu allen Leistungen, ohne Ausnahme, sowohl den geistigen, wie den körperlichen, ist.

You are correct. Gramatically, that *es* replaces *die rechte Zeit* in the second clause. You could drop in *die rechte Zeit* without any change in meaning.

The reason why it's not **sie** is because *die rechte Zeit* and *der Morgen* aren't different things by definition. That's the equation made up in the first clause. *Die rechte Zeit* is a **Prädikativ** ("nominative object"). In such cases, **es** or **so etwas** is used, instead of *er/sie* or *so einer/eine*.

Predicatives are often verb phrases. No one could ask for a gender match:

> Laura ist **spät dran**. Doch obwohl sie **es** ist, warte ich auf sie.

It's the same for predicatives with nouns in them:

> Musik ist **die beste Medizin**. Doch obwohl sie **es** ist, nehme ich weiter meine Pillen.

Such predicative "equations" with the subject are made with the verbs *sein*, *werden*, *bleiben*, *gelten als* and *sich erweisen als*.

> Der Smart gilt als **lahme Krücke**. Tatsächlich ist er **es** nicht, sondern erwies sich im Test als **ziemlich spritzig**.

Answer (score 0):

"Es" refers to the whole previous clause, that is: "Hiezu ist der Morgen die rechte Zeit". However, this sentence sounds a bit clumsy.

Comment: That sentence doesn't sound clumsy but poetical.

Comment: Es ist von Schopenhauer.

Comment: I have to disagree; *er* maps to *Morgen*, *es* to *rechte Zeit*, the *ist* follows at the end of the sentence.

Comment: I think it only refers to "die rechte Zeit": "Wie er (wer? der Morgen) es (was? die rechte Zeit) ist".

Comment: Thank you for your answers. This is the point of my question. Shoundn't the pronoun agree with the gender of Zeit, i.e., be feminine?